# What is and how to produce "cursor lost update" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

I read [**A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels**](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/02/24/a-critique-of-ansi-sql-isolation-levels/), then it talks about **cursor lost update** as shown below:

[image]

But, I don't really understand it so cannot produce it in **MySQL**.

What is and how to produce **cursor lost update** in **MySQL**?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- initial state
insert into mytable set x = 100;

Trans 1                                Trans 2

start transaction;                     start transaction;

update mytable set x = 75;

                                       update mytable set x = 110;
                                       -- waits because row is locked by trans 1
                                       
commit;                                

                                       -- acquires lock
                                       -- update x = 110 succeeds

                                       commit;
                                       
select * from mytable;                 
-- shows 110
-- where did my value 75 go??
```

This happens irrespective of cursors. MySQL does not support `update where current of cursor` as some other implementations do, so the closest you can get is to issue discrete update statements.

Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html

> UPDATE WHERE CURRENT OF and DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF are not implemented, because updatable cursors are not supported.

Comment: Can I say "cursor lost update" is "lost update" or the part of "lost update"? because "cursor lost update" which you show above is almost or exactly the same as "lost update".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of "cursor lost update" unless there's something missing in the author's description about when transactions start and commit. In the case of MySQL, it's moot because they don't support updatable cursors.

Comment: Is the example which you show above the case of MySQL? Do you mean "cursor lost update" doesn't happen in MySQL?

Comment: I can't be certain because the author is not clear when they say it "involves a cursor." But if it relies on `UPDATE WHERE CURRENT OF CURSOR` then it definitely cannot happen in MySQL.

Comment: OK, now it's clear. In short, "cursor lost update" doesn't happen in MySQL. Yeah, of course, "cursor lost update" doesn't happen because "dirty write" doesn't happen not just in MySQL but also other databases.